# Shadow effect does not work in QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following code in which I try to show a shadow effect behind the QMainWindow, for which I use `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect`
to be able to get the shadow.

But when running the code does not suspend anything.

I already tried modifying the color and the offset but it did not work either

[image]

Code. Py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QGraphicsDropShadowEffect
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic


class CInicial(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("ConfiguracionInicial.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(99)
        self.shadow.setColor(QtGui.QColor(99,255,255))
        self.shadow.setOffset(4)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)



app = QApplication([])
ci = CInicial()
ci.show()
app.exec_()
```

. Ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>683</width>
    <height>482</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color:#5E5858;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QFrame" name="fContenedor1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>691</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.498, y1:1, x2:0.472, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(46, 46, 48, 255), stop:1 rgba(137, 137, 137, 255));</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>5</x>
       <y>9</y>
       <width>151</width>
       <height>21</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>10</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:white;
background:none;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Configuración Inicial</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the shadow effect is applied it is painted in the parent widget, so in the case of your CInicial it will have no effect. One solution is to create a parent widget and set the Initialize through a layout:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

class Container(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, window, parent=None):
        super(Container, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(window)
        lay.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        shadow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self,
            blurRadius=9.0,
            color=QtGui.QColor(99, 255, 255),
            offset=QtCore.QPointF(8.0, 8.0)
        )
        window.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

class CInicial(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CInicial, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("ConfiguracionInicial.ui",self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CInicial()
    container = Container(w)
    container.resize(640, 480)
    container.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not only drop the shadow but also make the corner rounded, here is the solution.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QMargins
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPainterPath, QBrush, QPen, QRegion, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QGridLayout, QLabel, \
    QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout


# shadow + rounded frame
class ShadowFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__()
        # main_window is main widget to show
        self.__main_window = main_window
        self.__initUi()

    def __initUi(self):
        # for frameless window/prevent occurrence of minor bugs
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint)
        # make basic background(which is dark) invisible to show shadow
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        # set the shadow
        self.__effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
        self.__effect.setBlurRadius(12.0)
        self.__effect.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 127))
        self.__effect.setOffset(0.0)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.__effect)

        lay = QGridLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.__main_window)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        # set the background and pen (looks like Windows 11 default window)
        pen = QPen(QColor(Qt.gray), 1)
        brush = QBrush(QColor(241, 241, 241, 255))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)

        # set rounded window
        path = QPainterPath()
        rect = self.rect()
        # set margin to each direction for giving the space to show shadow
        rect = rect.marginsRemoved(QMargins(5, 5, 5, 5))
        # rounded corner's radius
        radius = 12.0
        path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(rect), radius, radius)
        # set antialiasing to enhance quality of window
        painter.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.drawPath(path)

        return super().paintEvent(e)


# sample widget to put inside the shadow(+rounded) frame
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__initUi()

    def __initUi(self):
        lbl = QLabel()
        lbl.setText('Shadow window example')
        textEdit = QTextEdit()

        lay = QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(lbl)
        lay.addWidget(textEdit)

        mainWidget = QWidget()
        mainWidget.setLayout(lay)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
    # put inside the shadow(+rounded) frame
    window = ShadowFrame(widget)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Check my repo if you want to see the detail of it: https://github.com/yjg30737/pyqt-shadow-frame-window-example